# How to integrate Veracode SAST and DAST scan in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, veracode, gitlab-pipelines, sast

I am trying to integrate a SAST and DAST scan in a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. Here is my gitlab-ci.yml so far:

Pipeline Scan Static Analysis:

image: veracode/pipeline-scan:latest
stage: Security_Scan
only:
- Feature Branch
script:
- zip myapp.zip ./sample/*
- java -Dpipeline.debug=true -jar /opt/veracode/pipeline-scan.jar -vid $TEAM_ANALYSISCENTER_ID -vkey $TEAM_ANALYSISCENTER_KEY --file myapp.zip --issue_details true --gl_issue_generation true -jf results.json 2>&1 | tee policy_scan_output.txt
artifacts:
paths:
- results.json
- policy_scan_output.txt
when: always
name: "veracode-POLICY-SCAN-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
allow_failure: false

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: The scan times out when it reaches its 60 min limit.